# How does this batch code create unwanted files

Tags: linux, bash, batch-file

```
for file in `find . -name "*.po"` ; do msgfmt -o `echo $file | sed s/\.po/\.mo/` $file ; done
```

This code I found is creating multiple MO files in all subdirectories from PO files. At first time, it works well. But when I run it second time;

it shows some syntax error messages. I checked the PO files that the msgfmt is complaining but they were not existing before. They are created after running this code.

For example the file was secpolicy.po but it also created another secpolicy.po file.

What is wrong in that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely with the quoting. Since you don't quote the sed pattern, the shell interprets the backslashes and calls sed as

```
sed s/.po/.mo/
```

When you have a file named `secpolicy.po`, it will change it to `se.molicy.po`, which results in a call to

```
msgfmt -o se.molicy.po secpolicy.po
```

To fix this, change the `sed` to

```
echo $file | sed 's/\.po$/.mo/'
```

See the additional single quotes `'` and the end of string `$`.

If you have a file `abc.po`, it will match the dot `\.`, the string `po` and finally the end of line `$`, and then replace this match with `.mo`, resulting in `abc.mo`

Comment: But will this code touch other files? I mean: will abc.po be abc.mo, too?

Comment: @user1754665 I'm glad you asked. I fixed my answer and the sed pattern. I also added an explanation for sed matching `abc.po`.

Comment: now i have worse problems :/. eg it is trying to find n.momukextras.po which does not exist. The file had to be "nepomukextras.po"

Comment: Sorry, it is ok. It was my mistake :)